# SQL - Importar dados de um arquivo

Tags: mysql, sql, importação

Olá, Amigos como estão?

Bom estou enfrentando um problema para importar uma tabela criada anteriormente:

A seguinte mensagem retorno quando tento executar a importação no MySQL:

Static analysis:

> 3 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 4)
>
> Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 25)
>
> Unrecognized statement type. (near "Host" at position 0)
> Comando SQL: 'Host: localhost (Version: 5.5.27)
>
> /*!40101 SET >@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */

Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Host: localhost  (Version: 5.5.27)
>
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@C' at line 1"

Gostaria de saber o que posso fazer para que a importação seja concluída de forma positiva.

Fico no aguardo, obrigado!

Comment: Qual foi o comando SQL que você utilizou?

Comment: @AllanAndrade Estou fazendo aulas online, estou utilizando o EAZY PHP para emular o servidor local.

Então estou usando o PHP My Admin para administrar o MYSQL.

Usei o comando de importação do administrador.

Não sei se consigo usar um console no EASY PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui, fiz o seguinte processo:

Primeiro criei a tabela: 'cad_cliente'

Após isso cliquei em SQL e colei o seguinte código:

```
CREATE TABLE `cad_cliente` (
  `cd_cliente` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ds_cliente` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nr_cnpjcpf` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nr_ident` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ds_contato` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nr_ddd` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nr_telefone` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ds_endereco` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ds_complemento` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ds_bairro` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ds_cidade` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ds_estado` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nr_cep` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ds_razao` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tp_cliente` char(1) DEFAULT 'f',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cd_cliente`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Após criar as tabelas colei o seginte código:

```
INSERT INTO `cad_cliente` VALUES (16,'spacetec','2222222222222',NULL,'pedro','21','22530548','pedro@spacetec.com.br','av rio branco','37 1502','centro','rio de janeiro','RJ','24320000','spacetec soluÃ§oes tecnologicas','j');
```

Depois criei a tabela 'usuarios'

Cliquei em SQL e colei o código abaixo:

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `usuario_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sobrenome` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `usuario` varchar(32) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `senha` varchar(32) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `info` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `nivel_usuario` enum('0','1','2') COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `data_cadastro` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `data_ultimo_login` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `ativado` enum('0','1') COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`usuario_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

Repeti o processo de inserir os dados que estavam cadastrados no meu backup.

Então apenas separei cada parte do processo, funcionou perfeitamente.